# Single Table Inheritance in Go using gorm

Tags: go, go-gorm

I want to achive Single Table Inheritance in Go using gorm library, but i can't find a way to do it or any documentation related to it.
Do anyone have already done that or knows about it?

I tried `gorm:"discriminator"` and `gorm:"discriminator:value"` but it's not working.

Comment: Go gorm is not the same as groovy/grails gorm. The discriminator tags that you mention don't exist in Go's gorm. Inheritance doesn't exist in the same way in Go either. What are you trying to do? Can you post an MCVE?